# Visual studio post build event command line "for" syntax

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, post-build-event

`Solution1` : { `Project1` (windows form), `Project2` (class library) }

Trying to copy all .dll(s) I get from after compiling `Project1`, from the default directory (same as the .exe) to a `/lib` sub-folder.

```
if not exist Lib mkdir Lib
for %i in (*.dll) move /Y "$(TargetDir)%i" "$(TargetDir)Lib\%i"
```

I have problem with the `for %i in (*.dll)` syntax. What is the correct way of doing it?

Note: This would give no errors (but would copy only 1 .dll, not all):

```
if not exist Lib mkdir Lib
move /Y "$(TargetDir)first.dll" "$(TargetDir)Lib\first.dll"
```

Comment: Does that syntax work in a batch file?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have no idea, I will add a screenshot to show you where I put this code into

Comment: Afaik `for` also needs a `do`, so try `for %i in (*.dll) do move ...`

Comment: I know where you set it, you should try to make it working in a batch file. If it does, it will in VS.

Comment: @Scoregraphic `error with code 255`

Comment: At least in batch files you have to use %%i and not %i, does it help?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen This was the problem. When I tried with double `%` I forgot to use the double `%` on the later part of the command. I used double `%` only in the `for %%i` part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. You should use a double percentage `%%` and `do`:

```
for %%i in (*.dll) do move /Y "$(TargetDir)%%i" "$(TargetDir)Lib\%%i"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried with double `%` before, but I forgot to use double `%` in the later part of the command. The error I got wasn't too descriptive